# Android sdk file explorer showing nothing

Tags: android, file, sdk, explorer, android-virtual-device

I am using the Android AVD SDK File Explorer view, I have the emuator running as well, but the view isn't showing me any file listings.

This usually is not a problem, what would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the devices view, ensure that the device/emulator you are using for testing is selected.